# How to open Gmail from react-native and passing photos before it open

Tags: javascript, android, ios, email, react-native

I need to open Gmail from my React-Native app. I can do it just calling       `Linking.openURL(myurl);` Being `myurl` a mailto url. It works, I open Gmail with the params I have in `myurl`. The problem is that I can't pass images this way and if I want to attach images to the mail I have to do it inside Gmal app and I would like choose these images from my own app and then pass it to the gmail attached. There exists a way to do it? Should it be possible in iOS with default mail app too?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `react-native-mail` package to open the email app and add everything you need. 
Works well for me.

https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail